# What does "Error in the pull function" mean while executing ffmpeg command?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to generate a video from multiple video sources (https urls).

If I use say 8 video sources it works as expected. But if I need say 30 sources, it starts to work as expected, but at some moment a lot of errors appear.

[image]

I believe the main one is `Error in the pull function.`.

Such a video-source appears in the output file but not a full requested part (e.g., I set trim=0:5, but ffmpeg generates only 3 seconds).

I tried different videos, different cropped parts, loaded sources to aws s3, but can't identify a "bad case", it's reproduced with different options.

My command looks like this:

```
ffmpeg -y
-i "https://player.vimeo.com/external/399541658.hd.mp4?s=5432956383527af00bb74b41c120bbb84ff3ac5e&profile_id=175&oauth2_token_id=57447761"
...
-i "https://player.vimeo.com/external/464966383.hd.mp4?s=648aa8277259c499f1d05d6330f9922932c080a6&profile_id=175&oauth2_token_id=57447761"
-i "https://test.com/development/videos/dc3c32cf9a194db1bb52/sources/5q5e3j2h57.mp3"
-filter_complex "[0:v]trim=0:5.64,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=1920x1080,setdar=16/9[v0];[1:v]trim=0:8,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=1920x1080,setdar=16/9,loop=0:32767[v1]; ... [10:v]trim=0:13,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=1920x1080,setdar=16/9[v10];[v0] ... [v10] concat=n=11:v=1 [video];[11:a] atrim=0:99.29 [audio]"
-vsync 2 -map [video] -map [audio] output.mp4
```

When I downloaded all sources to my local machine and tried to use them in the ffmpeg command it worked fine without errors.

Also, I figured out that it depends on the CPU. When I restricted my CPU the errors appeared earlier. And some commands might produce errors with a restricted CPU but finished successfully with no CPU restriction.

As I understand, for some reason, ffmpeg fails to receive a particular part of a file data, but I believe it should retry to receive lost packages (it's https).

And I don't understand, how it could be related to CPU or sources quantity.

By not understanding the core of evil, I can think about 2 ways (both ugly):

1. to download all sources and generate the final video from local files;
2. to chunk sources, generate intermediate outputs for each chunk (and save locally), and concatenate them into the final one.

Any better suggestions or at least where to seek?

Comment: My vote goes to your 2nd "ugly" solution. You are indeed taxing CPU (and network) a lot by simultaneously performing these parallel tasks. Forget the issues you're facing, I expect your second approach will run a lot faster than all-in-one approach (assuming saved on a fast NVMe/SSD drive). Video filtering operation is performed on decompressed data, meaning each buffer takes up a chunk (MB's) of memory and for sure CPU cache. Swapping of cache content with RAM is an expensive process, and having all these streams concurrently forces you to do so very often.